# Magic Mouse not working Properly after upgrading to macOS High Sierra!

Tags: macos, mac, software-update, mouse, high-sierra

Today I upgraded my late 2014 iMac to macOS High Sierra, for the first few hours the mouse was working fine (even before upgrading to High Sierra) but after a few hours it suddenly started malfunctioning the left  or the right click is not working properly then double tap to zoom is not working properly even selecting a text is not happening properly. Everything is hanging and freezing with the mouse gestures after updating to High Sierra!

Comment: Have you tried using your Magic Mouse with another Mac?

Comment: What is your battery/charge level? I initially had keyboard problems with my wireless keyboard but I replaced the batteries and now things are fine.

Comment: @oa- I haven't tried with other macs

Comment: @jmh Battery level full!